# API Testing.How to manage Payload

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-serenity

I want to test a API (Post method). I have to test this API by changing all the available parameters. For EG in Test case one I only change the user Name, in Test case 2 I change only the password and henceforth.

My API looks something like below :

```
{
          "schemas": [
                         "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
                         "urn:ibm:params:scim:schemas:extension:bean:agc:2.0:User"
          ],
          "name": {
          },
          "userName": "GROUPTEST12134",
          "password": "Asdfg12@sdd",
          "emails": [{
                         "value": "steve.hok123@awe.com"
          }],
          "phoneNumbers": [{
                        "value": "70422330098"
          }],

          "urn:ibm:params:scim:schemas:extension:bean:agc:2.0:User": {

          }
          }
```

I am successfully able to test it by below method :

```
    String urlParameters = "{\"schemas\": [\"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User\",\"urn:ibm:params:scim:schemas:extension:bean:agc:2.0:User\"],\"name\": {},\"userName\": \"GROUPTEST12138\",\"password\": \"Asdfg12@sdd\",\"emails\": [{\"value\": \"steve.hok1234@awe.com\"}],\"phoneNumbers\": [{\"value\": \"\"}],\"urn:ibm:params:scim:schemas:extension:bean:agc:2.0:User\": {}}";

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/scim+json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/scim+json");
    con.setRequestProperty("realm", "Ideas");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + BearerToken);
```

But I am looking for some way where I don't have to manage this  `urlParameters`.

Can you please some ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: "But I am looking out at some way where I dont have to manage this urlParameters" what do you mean? Could you clarify where you are "managing" the url parameters in your example that you'd like to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

3 possibilities:

In code- GSON library is quite nice.  You might look into it.

In files- I've seen JSON that's commonly used maintained in separate files.  Not really my preference, but it has its place for highly re-used JSON, or if you have a lot of boilerplate.

emails- you might want to remove steve's email from your JSON and scrub it from PII in the future.